# Is there a way to stop the icmp echo listener service without dropping messages?

Tags: 14.04, networking, ping

I'm new on the networks area.

I'm trying to stop the automatic handling of icmp messages (specifically the icmp messages used by "Ping" command) in my computer with ubuntu 14.04.

I have researched about how to do this and the found ways make the OS to drop the received messages. But my goal is to run my own listener which will handle the received messages and forward to embedded devices through an USB port, so the messages must not to be dropped by the OS.

Is there a way to disable or change the icmp echo listener service without recompiling the linux kernel?

Comment: What have you already tried? Please add specific details to the body of your question.

Comment: I have not tried anything, because every way I found makes Ubuntu to drop the received ICMP messages, so I still did not find a way to perform this.